# Groovy version inside Gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have upgrade gradle on my local machine.

then i checked the version, it returned;

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.10.2
------------------------------------------------------------

    Kotlin DSL:   1.0-rc-6
    Kotlin:       1.2.61
    Groovy:       2.4.15
    Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.11 compiled on March 23 2018
    JVM:          1.8.0_171 (Oracle Corporation 25.171-b11)
```

the groovy version is ; 2.4.15.

And I want to upgrade the gradle to `4.10.2`  in my spring boot project, But I am using gradle `2.5.0` in my project.

is it caused any problem?

can we use `2.5.0` or any other groovy version in gradle `4.10.2`?

What does the gradle's groovy version on my local machine mean?

Comment: It won't cause a problem

Answer (score 1):

There will be no foreseeable problems.  It's basically like this: Gradle utilizes Groovy to run it's tasks - and in those you have this Groovy version at disposal.  In the end it's just the build tool -- it's supposed to do a proper job at isolating class-path/-loading.

The Groovy plugin in Gradle will take care to pick up the proper version from your compile-time dependencies.  So unless you are doing things in your tasks or mess with configurations, you should be pretty safe.

Since you mentioned Spring Boot: be sure to pin your Groovy version with `ext['groovy.version'] = '2.5.3'` though, or else you end up with the problem described above due to the ways the Spring Boot plugin deals with dependencies.